# How would you say "She said goodbye too many times before." in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The refrain of the Maroon 5's song "This Love" contains the verse "*She said goodbye too many times before.*". How would you translate that verse into Latin? My attempt would be "*Ea dixit 'Vale!' plurimis temporibus abhinc.*", but I am not sure that's correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That translation strikes me as overly literal, trying to keep a match for each English word. I'd go more idiomatic with this.

For example, unless it's important to emphasize the "she", I would leave out the pronoun and let the verb's ending handle it. Similarly, I wouldn't use a word for "before". I would use either the perfect tense (if the intention is "before now") or the pluperfect (for "before then") and let the aspect of the verb carry that information.

There's actually a single Latin verb for "say goodbye", though it's very similar to your phrasing! *Valedīcō*, *valedīcere*, the ancestor of English "valedictorian" (the person who gives the farewell speech).

Finally, for "too many times", two phrasings come to mind. *Totiēns* means "so many times", emphasizing the repetition, while *nimium* (or its variants, there are plenty) means "too much", emphasizing the excess. I'm not aware of any phrase that emphasizes both the repeated action and the excess of it at the same time, like English "too many times" does.

So I would cut this down to something like *nimium valedīxit* or *totiēns valedīxit*: "she bade farewell too much before" or "she bade farewell so many times before".

(Of course, since this is a matter of style, others can and will disagree completely. Literalism in translation isn't necessarily a bad thing just because I dislike it stylistically.)

Comment: Nimium valedixit omits the subject but I think it's a relevant part of the original phrase - we are talking about "she". So perhaps illa nimium valedixit is more accurate? Or if not, can you perhaps expand to explain why we would omit the subject?

Comment: @Sklivvz it's not uncommon to omit words if they can be inferred from the sentence (ie through verbs). Saves valuable chisel time.

Comment: @Sklivvz Latin is what's called a "pro-drop" language, meaning that subject pronouns usually aren't written. The ending of the verb indicates who's doing the action instead. Including a pronoun for the subject puts a lot of emphasis on it: "_she_ was the one who said goodbye".

Comment: I know a little bit of Latin, I know you can drop the subject, but that's understood. However, the sentence as you wrote equally applies to both genders. The original English one only applies to a person with feminine pronouns.

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, but if the context refers to this person enough to make it clear who "she" is, it should also make it clear who "he/she/it/they" is. I don't know the song, but I doubt losing the gender marking will actually create any ambiguity; imo, adding an emphatic _illa_ changes the meaning significantly more.

Comment: Forcing a choice of gender might be seen as a limitation of the English language that could be profitably left behind during transition.

Comment: Including "illa" is helpful if you are trying to sing a Latin language cover of the song and need the syllables to make the original melody work. The original phrase has ten syllables, so "illa nimium valedixit" comes close. That said, the last word "before" is sung as a melisma covering six notes in the original song, so I suppose you could always "Gregorian chant" it.

Answer (score 10):

Cicero provides a possibility for "too many times" with *nimium saepe*:

> Quare "bene et praeclare" quamvis nobis saepe dicatur; "belle et festive" **nimium saepe** nolo (Cicero, *De Oratore* 3.101.2)

I think the meaning is even clearer with Seneca's *Medea*:

> Quodsi **nimium saepe** vocari quereris votis, ignosce, precor:
> But if you protest at **too frequent** a summons from my entreaties, forgive me, I pray:

Cicero uses *nimium* joined with *saepe* often, perhaps too often, since it's rarely found in other others (once in Seneca, the above passage, and I think twice in Ovid, but I haven't translated the passages in full to see if they belong together or if *nimium* goes with another word).

You could also easily just use the comparative or superlative forms of *saepe*, which would get the point across. In searching the Loeb library, I found several translators who have done that, so it's not just my intuition.

While Draconis is right that you don't need to translate "she", you might consider it if you want to single the subject out. For this, you could use *illa*, "that woman." For this particular sense of *illa*, see Lewis & Short:

> C. Opp. to hic, **to indicate that object which is the more remote**, either as regards the position of the word denoting it, or as it is conceived of by the writer; v. hic, I. D.—

So saying *illa valedixit* would have the same sense as the English "that woman."

I really only bring this up because the previous line has (and the song is called) "this love," so it provides a nice contrast: *hic amor, illa mulier.*

Comment: My only nitpick is that I wouldn't use that Catullus line as an example, since it's a fairly faithful translation of a Greek poem that uses a pronoun there. (I do think _illa_ is potentially a good choice here though.)

Comment: @Draconis Yes, very true, but it was the first thing that came to mind. If I think of a better example, I'll swap it out.

Comment: While the discussion of how to translate parts of the sentence is very interesting, to properly answer the question, the final sentence combining those parts really should be in it. _Illa nimium saepe valedixit,_ then?

Comment: I don’t really think the contrast works in this particular context. There isn’t an actual contrast between ‘this love’ and ‘she’ in the English (along with the person singing, ‘she’ _is_ the other half of ‘this love’, after all). Going a bit freer, I think I would leave out _illa_, but add in the object, which is implicit in the English original, and instead saying _mihi nimium valedixit_, or perhaps even _a me totiens abiit_ (‘she has left/abandoned me so many times’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You are free to write your own answer.